# Получение Id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, как можно передать `id radiobutton`'a в пост запросе если  у меня несколько... и у каждого свой `id`

Пример:

```
*@html.RadioButton("name", "value", new {id = 1});
```

я легко могу получить значение ("`value`") получаю я ее с помощью параметра (`formCollection`), но мне также важно получить "`ID`"

Comment: Как вы заметили, именно "value" используюется для передачи нужных данных на сервер. Поэтому запишите ваш id в параметр "value".
А в вашем примере id добавиться как атрибут в сгенерированный html-тэг.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно разобраться в простых вещах. Например, на [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form) есть хорошее описание html-тэга `<form>` и описание как происходит передача данных сервер. Оттуда станет понятно, что передаются пары name=value. Если есть какое-то значение, которое нужно передавать на сервер, но при этом не показывать пользователю как текстовое поле, то существует тип поля hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="secret" value="ID">
```

который будет скрыт от глаз пользователя, но при отправке формы передастся на сервер.